# 'Nesting too deep' error while retrieving JSON using HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, httparty

I am writing a very simple proxy wrapper for the reddit api so I can make cross domain JSONP requests (reddit does not allow JSONP calls to my knowledge).

I am using the HTTParty gem to make the call out and retrieve the response, which I immediately render out as json.

I am retrieving the subreddit json perfectly fine so far with this as my route:

```
  match "r/:name" => "api#subreddit"
```

... and this as my controller action:

```
def subreddit
    render :json => HTTParty.get("http://www.reddit.com/r/" + params[:name] + "/.json"), :callback => params[:callback]
end
```

As an example, the JSON that comes back is similar to this: http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json

My problem is when I attempt to grab the comments for a particular thread.

My route is as so:

```
match "r/:name/comments/:id" => "api#comments"
```

... and my controller action is this:

```
  def comments
    render :json => HTTParty.get("http://www.reddit.com/r/" + params[:name] + "/comments/" + params[:id] + "/.json"), :callback => params[:callback]    
  end
```

The JSON that I want back can be seen here: http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/rhzgc/.json

When I call this action, however, I receive the following error message:

```
MultiJson::DecodeError in ApiController#comments
Nesting of 20 is too deep
```

The full stack trace follows:

```
json (1.6.6) lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
json (1.6.6) lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
multi_json (1.2.0) lib/multi_json/engines/json_common.rb:9:in `decode'
multi_json (1.2.0) lib/multi_json.rb:81:in `decode'
httparty (0.8.1) lib/httparty/parser.rb:116:in `json'
httparty (0.8.1) lib/httparty/parser.rb:136:in `parse_supported_format'
httparty (0.8.1) lib/httparty/parser.rb:103:in `parse'
httparty (0.8.1) lib/httparty/parser.rb:66:in `call'
httparty (0.8.1) lib/httparty/request.rb:222:in `parse_response'
httparty (0.8.1) lib/httparty/request.rb:192:in `handle_response'
httparty (0.8.1) lib/httparty/request.rb:75:in `perform'
httparty (0.8.1) lib/httparty.rb:391:in `perform_request'
httparty (0.8.1) lib/httparty.rb:343:in `get'
httparty (0.8.1) lib/httparty.rb:423:in `get'
app/controllers/api_controller.rb:12:in `comments'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run__2872109728488784816__process_action__2261783022290592822__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:89:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/emcummings/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/emcummings/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/emcummings/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

What am I doing wrong here? If the JSON is too big to parse (I find that sort of hard to believe!) what can I do?

**EDIT:**

Looks like dropping back to the standard NET::HTTP lib solved my problem:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/rhzgc/.json")    
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
render :json => response.body, :callback => params[:callback]
#OK!
```

... but I still am curious why I am failing this same call with HTTParty!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that the JSON is too large. It's nested too deeply. `HTTParty` tries to decode the results that it gets automatically. Following your stack trace, and the `HTTParty` dependencies, it relies on `multi_json` which is using the `json` gem.

Inside of `json` there is [`lib/json/pure/parser.rb`](https://github.com/flori/json/blob/master/lib/json/pure/parser.rb). The default max depth set is set in there, specifically on line 79. Something in your returned JSON is 20+ levels deep, triggering the exception.

```
 if !opts.key?(:max_nesting) # defaults to 19
   @max_nesting = 19
```

Comment: Interesting - I figured it had to do with a json parser somewhere inside of HTTParty - is there a reason for an arbitrary limit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that JSON gem is the same one that nearly everything else uses by default, Rails included. HTTParty is just indirectly requiring it via multi_json. As for why they chose 19 for the default limit, I have no idea. It's an option that can be set, but I'm not sure if HTTParty exposes that easily or not.

Comment: HTTParty doesn't seem to expose setting any options on the underlying json parser - [it doesn't pass an options hash(https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty/parser.rb#L114) into the load or decode methods.

Answer (score 3):

Switched to the OJ JSON parser by adding the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'oj'
```

and this issue resolved itself.

Comment: This worked great for me too; this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this can be worked around by calling `to_json` with the `max_nesting` option set.

```
json = obj.to_json(max_nesting: 50)
```