# HTTParty.get with callback causes MultiJson::DecodeError.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, httparty

I'm using HTTParty to make calls to an API. When I have callback in the url it causes MultiJson::DecodeError:

```
MultiJson::DecodeError in PagesController#home

756: unexpected token at '12345({"label":"daydata","data":[[1335484800883,69586],
[1335571201001,17725]]});
```

My get call looks like this:

```
@data = HTTParty.get("http://powermeters.appspot.com/getdays?id=1234567890&from=2012-04-24&to=2012-04-29&callback=12345")
```

Does anyone know what is causing this, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the response is javascript, not JSON.  To fix it you can do:

```
response.gsub! /^\d+\((.*)\);?$/m, '\\1'
```

or something similar.

Comment: Yep, looks like a JSONP service, where you specify a callback to execute on your own website, via a `<script>` tag, either explicitly, or via some sort of client library.

Comment: @d11wtq Mm, ok. Is it possible to get the request in a Rails controller, I do some additional calculations on the data. Or do I have go get it from Javascript and then pass it to my controller, and  how would a script like that look? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try @pguardiario's suggestion of just stripping away the function call that is wrapped around it?

Comment: @d11wtq Yes, I tried, but I didn't get it to work. The app seems to crash as soon as I make the get request with HTTparty so I don't know if I will have a response to gsub!. Do you know where I should put it?

Comment: I finally got it to work, by using @pguardiario's answer and by changing from HTTParty to Net:HTTP.get_response, as of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917666/nesting-too-deep-error-while-retrieving-json-using-httparty. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the parser. A simple example is below.

The `if MultiJson...` is pulled straight from HTTParty's json parser

```
class Foo
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://foo.bar"

  parser lambda { |body,_|
    new_body = body.gsub(/^\d+\((.*)\)$/, '\1')
    if MultiJson.respond_to?(:adapter)
      MultiJson.load(new_body)
    else
      MultiJson.decode(new_body)
    end
  }
end
```