# set json max_nesting option from within Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm migrating a Ruby on Rails application from 3.0 to 3.1 and ran into some problems with the change of the JSON backend.

The line `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(some_variable)` gives me the MultiJson::DecodeError `nesting of 20 is too deep`.
The variable I'm trying to decode is indeed heavily nested (max 29 levels).

The maximum nesting level should be changeable with the `:max_nesting` option (['Nesting too deep' error while retrieving JSON using HTTParty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917666/nesting-too-deep-error-while-retrieving-json-using-httparty)) but this doesn't seem to work.

Both `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(some_variable, :max_nesting => false)` and `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(some_variable, :max_nesting => 100)` result in the same error.

Is there a way to pass the `max_nesting` option or set it application wide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveSupport::JSON` uses the multi-json gem for encoding and decoding operations. The multi-json gem supports a variety of engines, and supported options will differ between them.

You can check which engine you are using by running

```
require 'multi_json'
puts MultiJson.engine
```

Mine was `MultiJson::Adapters::Yajl` but other options are possible as well. Multi-json doesn't seem to pass options to each engine in the same way, so I'd recommend using the JSON-gem directly.

If you're using the json-gem, you could just skip the ActiveSupport-chain and parse your data using [JSON.parse](http://flori.github.com/json/doc/classes/JSON.html#method-i-parse), to which you can pass the `:max_nesting` option directly.

Comment: Using `JSON.parse(some_variable, :max_nesting => false)` fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this monkey-patch

```
module JSON
  class << self
    def parse(source, opts = {})
      opts = ({:max_nesting => 100}).merge(opts)
      Parser.new(source, opts).parse
    end
  end
end
```